# Who and when have charged the battery of the Yamato cannon for the final attack?

Tags: space-battleship-yamato

At the final scene of the "[Space Battleship Yamato (2010 film)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Battleship_Yamato_(2010_film))", the battleship moves at full speed towards the enemy, and then the (blocked) cannon is fired, destroying both ships.

Is there any explanation on why the cannon is ready, when we have just seen the destruction of the machine department (and the death of the senior engineer) shortly before? In the beginning of the movie, the engineer and his devices seem actively participating in the process of firing the cannon, charging the battery. Now Kodai simply presses the trigger and this is enough.

Who and when have charged the battery for the final attack?